# ElasticSearch position in index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm considering the use of Elasticsearch to build a rank. If I index a list of elements that is ordered according to a score. Can I query by an element name and get its position on the Index?

e.g i build an index with two elements:

"Element1", score: 8
"Element2", score: 7
"Element3", score: 10

When I query by "Element2" I would like to obtain position = 3

Comment: Can't you just store that information in your index? might be the easiest solution. `{"element": {"score": 8, "position": 2}}`

Comment: Well, the problem is that I would like Elastic Search to calculate that Index position for me. In other words: what I want to obtain is an integer that tells me the position of an element in an Elastic Search Index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch query SQL Server LAG function analog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779002/elasticsearch-query-sql-server-lag-function-analog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't know the place until it actually collects results and it collects results only to send them back to client. So, there is really no way to just get the place without going through results until you find the document you are looking for. If sending all these results to client doesn't work for you, you can write a plugin that will do it on the server side.