# Elasticsearch query SQL Server LAG function analog

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a SQL Server [LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx)/[LEAD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125(v=sql.110).aspx) functions analog in Elasticsearch.

Assume I have a list of documents in result set found by particular criteria. The result set is also ordered in some order.

I know the id of one of the documents in that result set and I need to find next and/or previous document in the same result set.

SQL Server 2012 and above has `LAG/LEAD` functions to get next/previous row in the recordset. So I wondering if there is such functionality in the elasticsearch.

Could you please point me on the corresponding documentation/examples please?

Comment: I see your bounty, @dmitry-polushkin. here what I found by my own: there is no known analogs. for my purposes I've found that its enough to mark each result returned from ES with an index number and later search with the same filter\sorting options but requesting results with skip option set to (index-1) and take set to 3. so I'll get previous, current and next items in the list.

Comment: Can you provide a short example?

Comment: In other words is it possible to get ordered position of each document in a sorted search?

Comment: PS. What I've found so far:
http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Can-ElasticSearch-sort-data-that-is-stored-as-a-linked-list-td4056166.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495761/elasticsearch-position-in-index
http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Getting-position-of-document-in-search-results-td2815171.html

Comment: @DmitryPolushkin sorry for silence. no, I haven't fond such possibility. I assume that the order result doesn't change for the same request, so I can take results with paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't.  Lots of stuff from relational land doesn't translate directly into Elasticsearch land.  What do you want to do with LAG/LEAD?  Just getting the ids is simple enough by asking for more results and looking up or down the list.  I imagine its something more fun but I don't want to speculate.

Comment: excaxtly what LAG/LEAD do. could you show me some query on getting document by id and retrieving the next/previous record in optimal way?